# plagiatös oder plagiatoid?

Tags: etymology, adjective

Vor kurzem hab ich/musste ich "plagiatös" als Adjektiv lesen. Wiktionary listet es nicht. Über den Sinn der Adjektivierung dieses Wortes kann man streiten.

Ich frage mich nur, wenn man es adjektivieren wollte, was das passende Suffix wäre. Das -ös Suffix ist kein dt. und auch eher selten. Hört sich phonetisch am besten an, kann das ausreichender Grund sein? Von der bekannten Bedeutung des -oid Suffixes würd ich es hier präferieren. Eine plagiatoides Werk, ein Werk, das Eigenschaften eines Plagiates aufweist.

Comment: Ich würde solche ausgefallenen Adjektive überhaupt nicht verwenden. Das kann man mit Plagiat auch ausdrücken.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wie [Takkat](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2758/plagiat%C3%B6s-oder-plagiatoid/2767#comment6346_2759) schon andeutet: Mit „Plagiat“ kann man sowohl den „Täter“ (also den Plagiator), die Handlung (das Plagiieren) als auch das Ergebnis (das Plagiat) in Verbindung bringen. Umgekehrt kann man einer Person, einer Handlung sowie einem Werk entsprechende Eigenschaften zuschreiben. Daraus ergeben sich m. E. drei mögliche (! – nicht zwingend gebräuchliche) Adjektivgruppen:

- Person: Basiswort „Plagiator“; als Derivation dürfte nur [Suffigierung](http://canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-A/N-To-A/Suffig.html) in Frage kommen; am weitesten verbreitet wohl „[-isch](http://canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-A/Suffixe/isch.html)“, ergibt „[plagiatorisch](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/plagiatorisch)“ (siehe auch die [Wortbildungsanalyse bei canoo](http://canoonet.eu/services/Controller?dispatch=wordformation&input=plagiatorisch&features=(Cat%20A)&country=D&lookup=caseInSensitive)): ein plagiatorischer Forscher;
- Handlung: Basiswort „plagiieren“. Hier am ehesten [Konversion](http://canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-A/V-To-A/Konvers.html) mit [Partizip Präsens](http://canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-A/V-To-A/Konvers.html#Anchor-Partizip-49575): „Er definiert plagiierend, dass …“.
- Resultat: Basiswort „Plagiat“, Derivation des Adjektivs wohl nur durch Nutzung des [Partizips Perfekt des Verbs](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Finit-Infinit/Part2.html#Anchor-Das-49575) „plagiieren“: die plagiierte Dissertation. „Plagiatös“ und „plagiatoid“ wären zwar theoretisch möglich (Ableitung vom Substantiv mit Fremdsuffixen), sind aber m. E. völlig ungebräuchlich.

Comment: +1 denke auch eher ungebräuchlich. Hätte evtl. noch den Kontext angeben sollen, find ich aber gerade nicht mehr. Fiel mir nur bei faschistoid-Frage wieder ein, darum diese Frage

Answer (score 4):

Duden führt ["plagiiert"](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/imitiert) als Synonym für imitiert auf, das wie ["plagiierend"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2758/plagiatos-oder-plagiatoid/2760#2760) vom Verb ["plagiieren"](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/plagiieren) gebildet wird.

> Herrenchiemsee ist kein barockes Schloss, sondern ein **plagiiertes** und ins Niedliche umgelogenes Versailles, wie es zur Befriedigung nostalgischer Sehnsüchte auf einer Chiemsee-Insel Platz finden konnte. <sup>[Die Zeit 16, 2008](http://www.zeit.de/2008/16/WeltkulturImitat)</sup>
>
> Überall da, wo die Nachahmung nicht diese produktive Komponente in sich trägt, können wir weiter unserer romantischen Vorstellung eines schöpfenden Originalgenies nachhängen; und des Schurken, der **plagiierend** vorgibt, ein solches zu sein. <sup>[Die Zeit 3, 2011](http://www.zeit.de/kultur/literatur/2011-03/copycats-rezension)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Richtig ist glaube ich "plagiatorisch" - jedenfalls listet das mein Duden Fremdwörterbuch mit der Bedeutung "nach Art eines Plagiators" (oder auch "den Plagiator betreffend") auf.

Comment: ja, auch Duden online führt das Wort: *wie ein Plagiator handelnd*

Comment: Aber: ein plagiiertes Werk kann niemals *"plagiatorisch"* sein, allenfalls sein plagiierender Schöpfer, der plagiatorisch handelt. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Beide genannten Varianten erscheinen mir recht fragwürdig und bleiben mir beim Aussprechen im Halse stecken. Es scheint schwer zu sein, aus einem französischen Substantiv ein deutsches Adjektiv zu bilden.

Ich habe via Google noch `plagierend` gefunden und die Opera-Rechtschreibprüfung schlägt mir dazu `plagiierend` vor.